# What is the difference between isinstance('aaa', basestring) and isinstance('aaa', str)?

Tags: python, python-2.x, built-in-types

```
a='aaaa'
print isinstance(a, basestring)#true
print isinstance(a, str)#true
```

Answer (score 401, accepted):

In Python versions prior to 3.0 there are two kinds of strings "plain strings" and "unicode strings". Plain strings (`str`) cannot represent characters outside of the Latin alphabet (ignoring details of code pages for simplicity). Unicode strings (`unicode`) can represent characters from any alphabet including some fictional ones like Klingon.

So why have two kinds of strings, would it not be better to just have Unicode since that would cover all the cases? Well it is better to have only Unicode but Python was created before Unicode was the preferred method for representing strings. It takes time to transition the string type in a language with many users, in Python 3.0 it is finally the case that all strings are Unicode.

The inheritance hierarchy of Python strings pre-3.0 is:

```
          object
             |
             |
         basestring
            / \
           /   \
         str  unicode
```

'basestring' introduced in Python 2.3 can be thought of as a step in the direction of string unification as it can be used to check whether an object is an instance of `str` or `unicode`

```
>>> string1 = "I am a plain string"
>>> string2 = u"I am a unicode string"
>>> isinstance(string1, str)
True
>>> isinstance(string2, str)
False
>>> isinstance(string1, unicode)
False
>>> isinstance(string2, unicode)
True
>>> isinstance(string1, basestring)
True
>>> isinstance(string2, basestring)
True
```

Comment: Did this change in Python 3? Are the new `str` and `byte` still children of `basestring`? Would be worth adding a note about this.

Comment: @MestreLion: It changed; Py3 has no `basestring` and `str` and `bytes` both subclass `object` directly. But note that this makes sense, since Py2 `str` is not the same as Py3 `bytes`. `basestring` should be thought of as "character string", of which Py3 only has the `str`. Hence the `2to3` tool replaces `basestring` with `str`.

Comment: In python3 the `isinstance(string2, str)` will be `True` all strings are stored as unicoded

Answer (score 8):

All strings are basestrings, but unicode strings are not of type str. Try this instead:

```
>>> a=u'aaaa'
>>> print isinstance(a, basestring)
True
>>> print isinstance(a, str)
False
```

Answer (score 4):

Really what you're asking is the difference between the basestring and str class.

Str is a class that inherits from basestr.  But unicode strings also exist, as could other ones, if you wanted to make one.

```
>>> a = u'aaaa'
>>> isinstance(a, str)
False
>>> isinstance(a, basestring)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Basestring is the superclass of string. In your example, a is of type "str" thus, it is both a basestring, and a str