# Catch 0xC3 in a ut8 encoded string

Tags: python, encoding

I am encoding strings with `p.encode('utf-8')` into `utf-8`.
I than trying to catch what might have gone wrong with

```
def assert_encoding(s):
    try:
        if s is None or pd.isnull(s) or (not isinstance(s, basestring)) or s.decode('utf-8') :
            return True
    except UnicodeError:
        return False
```

A string goes through an `assert(encoding(s))` but then an `INSERT INTO` my Postfres database (configured for `UTF-8`) fails with the error saying that `0xC3 0x20` is not an UTF-8 supported byte sequence.

- Is there a loop-hole in assert_encoding?

Comment: On what object does the insertion fail? And wouldn't `not isinstance(s, basestring)` cover the two cases `s is None` and `pd.isnull(s)` already?

Comment: `pd.isnull(s)` catches `np.nan`, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe, but so does `not isinstance(s, basestring)`, doesn't it? After all `np.nan` is not a string.

Comment: You're right. that also holds for `inf`. I am afraid I have confused missing values with the column type. If you answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Mine was not an answer to your question, just nitpicking :). You should post your edit as an answer instead and then accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have perhaps the cause.

Given:

```
s = 'cil à cil'.decode('latin-1')
```

which we then encode into `utf-8`:

```
'cil à cil'.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')
```

Some cols are to long. I have to shorten them doing something like:

```
 'cil à cil'.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')[0:x]
```

where `x` is the number of characters, or at least what I *thought* was [the number of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153920/returning-the-first-n-characters-of-a-unicode-string).

In reality, by improperly setting `x`, I might cut the `utf-8` string at the wrong point.

```
'cil à cil'.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')[0:7].decode('utf-8')
```

And in my code, I check the encoding only before shortening the string.