# How to check if type of a variable is string?

Tags: python, string, variables, types

Is there a way to check if the type of a variable in python is a `string`, like:

```
isinstance(x,int);
```

for integer values?

Comment: Required reading on isinstance if you are learning python http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/ .

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979107/1145750

Comment: Be careful with ints since `isinstance(True, int) is True`.

Comment: `isinstance(x,str)` is correct in Python 3 (str is a basic type).

Comment: How about simply: `type(my_variable) is str`? [I made this an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string/68941793#68941793).

Answer (score 1550):

In Python 3.x, the correct way to check if `s` is a string is

```
isinstance(s, str)
```

The `bytes` class isn't considered a string type in Python 3.

---

In Python 2.x, the correct check was

```
isinstance(s, basestring)
```

`basestring` is the [abstract superclass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#basestring) of `str` and `unicode`. It can be used to test whether an object is an instance of either `str` or `unicode`.

Comment: @Yarin: No. But it doesn't matter, because Python 3.x is not meant to be compatible with Python 2.x at all.

Comment: I found that isinstance(s, str) works with py27, tested on : Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin.

Comment: @kakyo: The problem is that it will miss `unicode` objects, which should also be considered strings.  Both the type `str` and the type `unicode` have the common base class `basestring`, and this is what you want to check for.

Comment: @Yarin if you're porting something from 2.x to 3.x, you can always assign `basestring = str`.

Comment: @AdamErickson For compatibility with what exactly?  It doesn't help for compatibility with Python 3, since there is no `unicode` in Python 3.  My recommendation for compatibility between Python 2 and 3 is to use the "six" library.  (Specifically `isintance(s, six.string_types)` in this case)

Comment: I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'str' referenced before assignment` when I use `isinstance(s, str)` with python 3.9

Comment: @msoutopico This means you use `str` as the name of a local variable later in your function, shadowing the builtin with the same name. Don't do that, just rename it to something else.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I think I don't do that. The issue got fixed, indirectly. I think the reason for that error was that I was trying to convert to string (i.e. `str(x)`) something (`x`) that was `nan` (extracted from an empty cell in a spreadsheet). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @msoutopico No, that's not a possible explanation. The given error message can only possibly occur when the compiler infers that `str` is the name of a local variable. This is inferred statically, at compile time, so invalid values at runtime do not matter.

Answer (score 243):

I know this is an old topic, but being the first one shown on google and given that I don't find any of the answers satisfactory, I'll leave this here for future reference:

[six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) is a Python 2 and 3 compatibility library which already covers this issue. You can then do something like this:

```
import six

if isinstance(value, six.string_types):
    pass # It's a string !!
```

Inspecting the code, this is what you find:

```
import sys

PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3

if PY3:
    string_types = str,
else:
    string_types = basestring,
```

Comment: E.g. for a one liner: `value_is_string = isinstance(value, str if sys.version_info[0] >= 3 else basestring)`, where `>=` assumes any eventual Python 4+ keeps the `str` root class for strings.

Comment: six is not a part of the standard Python install, so almost by definition is non-portable. I want to write a simple Python app and have it "just work" for anybody who runs it. If I tell them "first, you need to install this *other* library just use my app", that's a big problem.

Comment: That's why the implementation code is there.

Comment: The `six` library seems to be available only for Python2 on my Mac. If its availability is version-specific, you might as well use one of the version-specific solutions in the first place.

Comment: What the code expands into is written there. You can just use that. The point is that other answers here are wrong, according to what the Python library considers a string type.

Answer (score 117):

In Python 3.x or Python 2.7.6

```
if type(x) == str:
```

Comment: I like the elegance of "if type(x) in (str, unicode):", but I see PyLint flags it as "unidiomatic".

Comment: Comparing types with `==` is explicitly discouraged by PEP8, and has several downsides in addition to be considered "unidiomatic", e.g. it does not detect instances of subclasses of `str`, which should be considered strings as well.  If you really want to check for exactly the type `str` and explicitly exclude subclasses, use `type(x) is str`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach So should isinstance be used instead to include the subclasses?

Comment: @sinekonata Yes, the most common and recommended way to check for strings is `isinstance(s, str)` in Python 3.x – see my answer above. Only if you have a specific reason to exclude subclasses (which should be rare), you should use `type(s) is str`.

Comment: `type(x) == str` doesn't work for unicode strings in Python2. `type(x) in (str, unicode)` is an error in Python3.

Answer (score 26):

you can do:

```
var = 1
if type(var) == int:
   print('your variable is an integer')
```

or:

```
var2 = 'this is variable #2'
if type(var2) == str:
    print('your variable is a string')
else:
    print('your variable IS NOT a string')
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Better to use something as `type(var) is int`, as using `==` to compare types is not recommended by PEP8

Answer (score 24):

### Use `type()` or `isinstance()`

I don't know why not a single answer before me contains this simple `type(my_variable) is str` syntax, but using `type()` like this seems the most-logical and simple to me, by far:

(tested in Python3):

```
# Option 1: check to see if `my_variable` is of type `str`
type(my_variable) is str

# Option 2: check to see if `my_variable` is of type `str`, including
# being a subclass of type `str` (ie: also see if `my_variable` is any object 
# which inherits from `str` as a parent class)
isinstance(my_variable, str)
```

The Python `type()` built-in function documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type. It states, in part, the following. Notice the note about `isinstance()`:

> `class type(object)`
> `class type(name, bases, dict, **kwds)`
>
> With one argument, return the type of an object. The return value is a type object and generally the same object as returned by `object.__class__`.
>
> The `isinstance()` built-in function is recommended for testing the type of an object, because it takes subclasses into account.

So, if you're checking the type of a class object instead of a simple variable, and you need to take subclasses into account, then use `isinstance()` instead. See its documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance.

### Example code:

```
my_str = "hello"
my_int = 7

print(type(my_str) is str)
print(type(my_int) is str)

print()
print(isinstance(my_str, str))
print(isinstance(my_int, str))
```

Output:

> ```
> True
> False
>
> True
> False
> ```

Answer (score 14):

The type module also exists if you are checking more than ints and strings. 
http://docs.python.org/library/types.html

Comment: More specifically, [`types.StringTypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.StringTypes).

Comment: types.StringTypes appears to no longer exist in Python 3 :(

Comment: `types.StringTypes` is not defined for Python3

Answer (score 13):

Edit based on better answer below.  Go down about 3 answers and find out about the coolness of basestring.

Old answer:
Watch out for unicode strings, which you can get from several places, including all COM calls in Windows.

```
if isinstance(target, str) or isinstance(target, unicode):
```

Comment: Good catch.  I didn't know about basestring.  It's mentioned about 3 posts down and seems like a better answer.

Comment: `isinstance()` also takes a *tuple* as the second argument. So even if `basestring` did not exist, you could just use `isinstance(target, (str, unicode))`.

Comment: In python 3.5.1, `unicode` does not appear to be defined: `NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined`

Answer (score 13):

since `basestring` isn't defined in Python3, this little trick might help to make the code compatible:

```
try: # check whether python knows about 'basestring'
   basestring
except NameError: # no, it doesn't (it's Python3); use 'str' instead
   basestring=str
```

after that you can run the following test on both Python2 and Python3

```
isinstance(myvar, basestring)
```

Comment: Or if you want to catch byte strings too: `basestring = (str, bytes)`

Answer (score 11):

Python 2 / 3 including unicode

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from builtins import str  #  pip install future
isinstance('asdf', str)   #  True
isinstance(u'asdf', str)  #  True
```

http://python-future.org/overview.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! There are dozens of various answers around the internet but the only good is this one.

The first line makes `type('foo')` being `unicode` by default in python 2, and the second one make `str` being instance of `unicode`. Thoses makes the code valid in Python 2 and 3. Thanks again !

Answer (score 10):

Lots of good suggestions provided by others here, but I don't see a good cross-platform summary.  The following should be a good drop in for any Python program:

```
def isstring(s):
    # if we use Python 3
    if (sys.version_info[0] >= 3):
        return isinstance(s, str)
    # we use Python 2
    return isinstance(s, basestring)
```

In this function, we use `isinstance(object, classinfo)` to see if our input is a `str` in Python 3 or a `basestring` in Python 2.

Comment: This will likely break in Python 4, consider `>=` at least.

Comment: be cleaner to check for six.string_types or six.text_type

Comment: @daonb importing an entire module just to do a one-line test is the thinking that causes crazy dependency trees and serious bloat to ruin what should be something short small and simple.  It's your call of course, but just say'n ...

Comment: @duanev if you're worried about Python 2/3 compatibility it's a better idea to be using six in the project anyways. Six is also a *single file* so dependency trees / bloat are not an issue here.

Comment: Also, at least on my Mac, `import six` is an error in Python3

Answer (score 9):

So,

You have plenty of options to check whether your variable is string or not:

```
a = "my string"
type(a) == str # first 
a.__class__ == str # second
isinstance(a, str) # third
str(a) == a # forth
type(a) == type('') # fifth
```

This order is for purpose.

Comment: This is a good compendium of ways to test a type. However in Python2, if you consider unicode to be a string type, this won't work.

Answer (score 8):

Also I want notice that if you want to check whether the type of a variable is a specific kind, you can compare the type of the variable to the type of a known object.

For string you can use this

```
type(s) == type('')
```

Comment: This is a terrible, terrible way to type check in python.  What if another class inherits from `str`?  What about unicode strings, which don't even inherit from `str` in 2.x?  Use `isinstance(s, basestring)` in 2.x, or `isinstance(s, str)` in 3.x.

Comment: @Jack, please read question, and also notice I do not write that it's the best way, just another way.

Comment: This is a bad idea for 3 reasons: `isinstance()` allows for subclasses (which are strings too, just specialised), the extra `type('')` call is redundant when you can just use `str` and types are singletons, so `type(s) is str` is going to be a more efficient test.

Answer (score 6):

Alternative way for Python 2, without using basestring:

```
isinstance(s, (str, unicode))
```

But still won't work in Python 3 since `unicode` isn't defined (in Python 3).

Answer (score 6):

Here is my answer to support both Python 2 and Python 3 along with these requirements:

- Written in Py3 code with minimal Py2 compat code.
- Remove Py2 compat code later without disruption. I.e. aim for deletion only, no modification to Py3 code.
- Avoid using `six` or similar compat module as they tend to hide away what
  is trying to be achieved.
- Future-proof for a potential Py4.

---

```
import sys
PY2 = sys.version_info.major == 2

# Check if string (lenient for byte-strings on Py2):
isinstance('abc', basestring if PY2 else str)

# Check if strictly a string (unicode-string):
isinstance('abc', unicode if PY2 else str)

# Check if either string (unicode-string) or byte-string:
isinstance('abc', basestring if PY2 else (str, bytes))

# Check for byte-string (Py3 and Py2.7):
isinstance('abc', bytes)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = '1000' # also tested for 'abc100', 'a100bc', '100abc'

isinstance(a, str) or isinstance(a, unicode)
```

returns True

```
type(a) in [str, unicode]
```

returns True

Comment: For Python 2.7.12 I had to remove the quotes:

type(a) in [str, unicode]

Comment: Won't work for Python3

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to depend on external libs, this works both for Python 2.7+ and Python 3 (http://ideone.com/uB4Kdc):

```
# your code goes here
s = ["test"];
#s = "test";
isString = False;

if(isinstance(s, str)):
    isString = True;
try:
    if(isinstance(s, basestring)):
        isString = True;
except NameError:
    pass;

if(isString):
    print("String");
else:
    print("Not String");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the *isinstance* function to make sure that the input data is of format *string* or *unicode*. Below examples will help you to understand easily.

```
>>> isinstance('my string', str)
True
>>> isinstance(12, str)
False
>>> isinstance('my string', unicode)
False
>>> isinstance(u'my string',  unicode)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing:

There doesn't seem to be a portable way to do it if you want both Python2 and Python3, and want to include unicode as well. I wound up using this idiom:

```
# Near the top of my program
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    basestring = str
```

Then any time I want to test an object to see if it's a string:

```
if isinstance(obj, basestring):
    ...
```

Frankly, I'm a little shocked that Python3 dropped basestring as well as  types.StringTypes. I see no reason to drop them, and keeping either of them would have made this problem solveable.

Answer (score -2):

```
s = '123'
issubclass(s.__class__, str)
```

Answer (score -6):

This is how I do it:

```
if type(x) == type(str()):
```

Comment: `type(str())` is a very roundabout way of saying `str`. Types are singletons, so `type(x) is str` is more efficient. `isinstance()` should be used instead, unless you have very good reasons to ignore subclasses of `str`.

Comment: if type(x) is str:

Answer (score -8):

I've seen:

```
hasattr(s, 'endswith')
```

Answer (score -14):

```
>>> thing = 'foo'
>>> type(thing).__name__ == 'str' or type(thing).__name__ == 'unicode'
True
```

Comment: In which case would you prefer `type(thing).__name__ == 'str'` over `type(thing) == str` or `isinstance(thing, str)`? Also `unicode` does not exist in modern versions of Python.