# How to check whether all elements in a list of lists are strings

Tags: python, string, performance, list

Suppose I have a list of list of strings like this:

```
l=[['a','kl_hg', 'FOO'],['b', 'kl_c', 'po']]
```

Now I would like to use an `if` command as follows (in pseudo-code!):

```
if allElementsOf(l).isString():
#do something
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string-in-python) I learned how to check a single variable whether it is a string. For a single list I could therefore do:

```
dummyL = ['a','kl_hg', 'FOO']
if all(isinstance(s, basestring) for s in dummyL):
#do something
```

and for my actual list `l` I could then do:

```
if all(isinstance(el, basestring) for sl in l for el in sl):
#do something
```

Is that the way to do it or is there a faster solution since that takes some time for huge lists of lists?

Comment: How could you possibly beat `O(m*n)`? You need to check each element in each list in the list! `all` already gives you short-cutting (i.e. the first element it finds that *isn't* a string will end the loop).

Comment: For large lists `chain.from_iterable(l)` might be a bit faster but the complexity is not going to change

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Thanks for the suggestion. I guess the solution you ha din mind looks like the one danihp posted?!

Comment: sorry @PadraicCunningham, I have seen your comment after post the answer!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I often thought this and then found a much more efficient solution. :)

Comment: @Cleb, yes, it is the fastest way in python to flatten large lists, that is about as good as you are going to get , your worst case is always going to be `O(n*m)`  and there is not really much you can do about that.

Comment: @danihp, don't worry about it

Comment: @Cleb it might have lower fixed costs, but the algorithmic complexity is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is right, [any flatting list short cut seems slowest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/842935). A [fastest way may be use itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/842935):

```
import itertools
l=[['a','kl_hg', 'FOO'],['b', 'kl_c', 'po']]
if all( isinstance(x, basestring) for x in  itertools.chain.from_iterable(l) ):
    ...
```

Comment: Nice, that works fine and seems faster than my approach. I upvote it and might accept it later (just in case something even better shows up). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's odd how anyone has told [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) built-in function:

```
seq = [['a','kl_hg', 'FOO'], ['b', 'kl_c', 'po', 13]]

def all_string(_iterable):    
    return not any([not isinstance(n, basestring) for i in _iterable 
                        for n in i])

all_string(seq) # returns False
```

The advantage when using [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function is that it does not evaluate the whole sequence, it returns when the first True value is found - In contrast to all().

Comment: Works fine as well! Thanks for the alternative solution, I upvote your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use recursion to solve this in the general case, for any level of nesting.  For example:

```
def all_strings(thing):
    if isinstance(thing, str):
        return True
    elif isinstance(thing, list):
        for subthing in thing:
            if not all_strings(subthing):
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False

>>> print all_strings('foo')
True
>>> print all_strings(['foo'])
True
>>> print all_strings(['foo',['foo']])
True
>>> print all_strings(['foo',[1, 'foo']])
False
>>>
```

Comment: Don't remember why I did not upvote this one; just came back to this old question and your solution works perfectly fine. Upvoted it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
for x in l:
    for a in range(3):
        if type((x[a])) == str:
            print(x[a], ' is a string')
```