# Is an integer converted from a string not a integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how come

```
int('1') != int()
True
```

I converted the string to int but the expression shows it is True.

Sorry.

Can Anyone tell me how to achieve this "If this is not an int then True"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many people mention it above, `int()` returns a 0.
In order to determine whether a variable is an integer or not, you must use`type`.
so you can check whether a variable is an int it by calling

```
type(int('1')) == int
```

which will return `true`.
If you are looking to check whether a variable is not int, just negate the code above as such:

```
type(int('1')) != int
```

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to check whether a number is equal to its type (and not actually doing that). It is not. Numbers are numbers, and types are types. To check the type, use `type()` or `isinstance()`:

```
>>> x = type(int('1'))
>>> y = isinstance(int('1'), int)
>>> x
<class 'int'>
>>> x == int
True
>>> y
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `int()` is:

```
>>> int()
0
```

And of course, `1` is never equal to `0`.

```
>>> type(int('1')) == int
True
>>> isinstance(int('1'), int)
True
```

Comment: Thanks how can I achieve "If this is not an int then true"?

Comment: Just negate the condition.

Answer (score 0):

`int()` evaluates to `0`

your code is basically `int('1') == 0`

This is `False`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> int()
0
>>> int('1')
1
```

`int()` returns 0, so the expression evaluates to `1 != 0` which is True. If you meant something more like:

```
>>> isinstance(int('1'), int)
True
>>> type(int('1')) == type(int())
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Default `int()` is 0

To check your value you can use You can use type:
`type(int('1'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
isinstance(int('1'), int)
```

or

```
type(int('1')) == type(int())
```

Both return `true`.

ref this thread [How to check if type of a variable is string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string), I believe it's same thing.

Answer (score 0):

From the result your got lets look at it this way.

The *function int()* does **casts** on values entered, in your case '1'. So it simply says:

```
cast '1' to an integer --> int('1') which gives 1

cast 'nothing' --> int() which gives '0'
```

So when you ask the question `int('1') != int()` which translates to:

```
is the value of the cast int('1') different from the value of the cast int()
```

then the answer should **rightfully** be **true** which is what you have. But if you had asked:

```
are their values the same, i.e. int('1') == int()
```

then the answer would have been **false**