# Python if statement if variable value is string or any Type

Tags: python

How can I make an if statement that will ask if my variable contains string or any type then if it is, then it will execute the code under my if statement.
Below code is just my experimentation but it does not work the way I hope it'll be.

```
def checkMyValues(*args):
    if isinstance(args, str) == True:
        print("it is a string!")

checkMyValues("haime")
```

but this does not output "it is a string!".

any help will be much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: You have `def` twice

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4843178/5351549

Comment: ops sorry. Just in here not in my actual python code.

Comment: The asterisk in front of the args in the definition line means, that all parameters are passed in a list. So you get a list, and its first element is of type string.

Comment: `*args` makes a tuple, and not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to check the list of arguments for the type, you should loop it rather than checking the tuple itself for its type. then it will give you the expected results. Below is the modified version of your code

```
def checkMyValues(*args):
    for each in args:        
        if isinstance(each, str) == True:
            print("it is a string!")
        else:
            print("Its not a string")

checkMyValues("haime", 20, '40.2')
```

Comment: Figured it out after a couple of minutes I ask this question. I got same solution as your answer thanks! Can remove the " == True" by the way and works just fine.

Comment: Cool. Yes, the isinstance() function returns a boolean value, it works fine without '=='.

Answer (score 0):

Using `*args` in your function will make args to be a `tuple` and not `str` that is why it won't print `it is a string`.

Try this

```
def checkMyValues(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, str): # Not need to compare == True
        print("it is a string!")

checkMyValues("haime")
```

More info on `*args` and `*kwargs` [here](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/)

Comment: Yea but I want it as *args because i'm working on a flexible number of arguments. I think I got it. I need to loop it first in a For loop and get each value of args before doing anything on it. Thanks btw

Comment: `*args` makes a tuple, not a list. Can be an important distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Remove * from args and it will work. Adding * to arguments makes it a non-keyworded argument (List). Thus your check fails.

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop over the args (which is a `tuple` of the arguments you are passing to the function):

```
def checkMyValues(*args):
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, str):
            print(arg, "is a string!")
```

which outputs:

```
checkMyValues("haime")
# haime is a string!

checkMyValues("haime", 7, [], None, 'strg')
# haime is a string!
# strg is a string!
```

Answer (score -1):

*args is a tuple not a string

```
def checkMyValues(*args): 
    for s in args:  
        z = type(s)
        if  z is str:
            print(s," is a string!")
        else:
            print(s," is not a string!")

checkMyValues("4","5",5)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand what do you mean, but according to your code. Maybe you need this.

```
def checkMyValues(args):
    if isinstance(args, str):
        print("is string")
```

Comment: Well, If you do not understand the question, you should clarify it **before** answer it.