# remove characters from the first items in list of lists

Tags: python, nested-lists, strip

I have a nested list and in every list the first item is a string that ends with `.abc`. I would like to remove all the `.abc` characters from my nested list.

Here's what I have got:

```
x = [['car.abc', 1, 2], ['ship.abc', 3, 4]]
```

And I would like to my nested list to be the following:

```
x = [['car', 1, 2], ['ship', 3, 4]]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple for loop.

```
x = [['car.abc', 1, 2], ['ship.abc', 3, 4]]
for i in x:
    i[0] = i[0].rsplit(".", 1)[0]
print(x)
```

Comment: Maybe better use `rsplit(".", 1)` in case there's another `.` inside the string.

Comment: Updated @tobias_k :)

Answer (score 1):

Using nested regular expressions and list comprehension:

```
>>> import re

>>> [[re.sub(r'.abc$', '', e) if isinstance(e, basestring) else e for e in l] for l in x]
[['car', 1, 2], ['ship', 3, 4]]
```

- `isinstance(e, basestring)` checks whether `e` is a string (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string)).
- For a string `e`, `re.sub(r'.abc$', '', e)` replaces the part you specified
- Otherwise `e` is untouched
- The preceding happens for any element `e` in a list `l`, for each `l` in `x`.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks! fixed.

Answer (score 0):

[Check online demo](https://repl.it/Hy05/1)

```
x = [['car.abc', 1, 2], ['ship.abc', 3, 4]]
new_x=[]
for lst in x:
  temp_lst=[]
  for item in lst:
    if(str(item)[-4:] == '.abc'):
      item = str(item)[:-4]
    temp_lst.append(item)
  new_x.append(temp_lst)

print(new_x)
```