# Unittest for Python/ Test Driven Dev

Tags: python, unit-testing, tuples

I am trying to start code using a test-driven approach. I have in English what I want my code to do and I am starting off with writing some unit tests. Below is my current code for my unit test:

```
import unittest

class Testing_Tuple(unittest.TestCase):
def test_tuple(self):
    Input = Testing_Tuple(True)
    self.assertEqual(type(Input[0]), str)
    self.assertEqual(type(Input[1]), str,
    self.assertEqual(type(Input[2]), int," Testing to make sure a tuple is returned")
```

I would like to create a class called car. The input to class `car` should be a single tuple that contains three elements: two strings and one integer. The first string will be the brand of the car (e.g. `"Honda"`, `"Ford"`), the second string will be the make of the car (e.g. `"corolla"`, `"mustang"`), and the integer will represent the miles per gallon the car gets.

Basically I want to above unit test to check if the input is a tuple by testing if element one is a string, element one is a string and element three is an integer. I am not receiving any errors with the current code but I just want to make sure that my logic is correct.

Comment: What is the purpose of `Input = Testing_Tuple(True)` when you seem to not refer to `Input` afterwards?

Comment: Ok, that edit makes things more clear.

Comment: @quamrana do you think this test would reasonably fail/ pass given my description?

Comment: Your test is now valid, but I'm not convinced this is what you really want to test. I would have somehow provided some dummy data for `Testing_Tuple()` to return and check: `self.assertEqual(Input, ('Ford','Mustang',4) )`

Comment: [`isinstance()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string) might be a good start.