# How to convert string number to int and avoid the string text before convert

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I would like to create the check condition string is string number or not
so, how I can do in python

```
x = "String"
y = "12"

if x is string:
   print("this is string")
if y is string:
   print("this is not string")
```

Comment: What is `string` that you set in if condition?

Comment: `if x is string` If you want to check the _type_ of x, this is the wrong way to do it.  Use `if type(x) is str` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if type of a variable is string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a string represents an int, without using try/except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except)

Comment: Both `x` and `y` are Python strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
array = ["String", "12"]

for item in array:
  try:
    int(item)
    print(f"{item} is not string")
  except:
    print(f"{item} is string")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.isdigit()` method to fulfill this.

```
x = "String"
y = "12"

if not(x.isdigit()):
   print("this is string")
if y.isdigit():
   print("this is not string")
```

Output:

```
this is string
this is not string
```