# i have a question about how to calculate the data types

Tags: python

How do I calculate the data type of `False` (notice the quotes around the word False!) and save it in a variable named `q7`, then print it out in python.

```py
q7 = "False"
print(type(q7))

q7 = False != False
print(q7)

q7 = str (5 % 2 == 0)
print(q7)

q7 = "False"
print(q7)

q7 = "Is 5 even? " + str(5 % 2 == 0)
print(q7)

q7 = str('str')
print(type(q7))
```

Comment: From `print(type(q7))`, it seems you already know how to get the type of something in Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if type of a variable is string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string)

Answer (score 0):

You described exactly what you have to do:

```
# [Access]  the data type of False (notice the quotes ...)
# save it in a variable named q7
q7 = type("False")

# print it out
print(q7)
```

"Calculate" is the wrong term.  You are merely looking up the data type, not "calculating" it.