# How to check if a return object is a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have written a function f(x) that either returns a dictionary or an error message.

```
def myfunc():
    try:
       return dictionary
    except BaseException as e:
       return e

return_value = myfunc()

if return_value a dictionary:
    do this
else:
    do that
```

I need to detect the type of return in another function f(y) which calls f(x).

How do I do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: Not pretty sure about this, but I guess you can just to `try ... catch` outside `myfunc()`, since on error the function will pass the exception to the caller.

Comment: @j1-lee: The exception is not propagated outside of `myfunc()`.

Comment: You should not `return` an exception instance. You should just let it be raised. That's *the point* of how exceptions work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example does not follow normal best practices, but you would do the following:

```
if type(return_value) is dict:
```

or

```
if isinstance(return_value, dict):
```

Answer (score 2):

```
isinstance(return_value, dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check a value's type as follows:

```
if type(return_value) == dict:
    print("It is a dictionary.")
else:
    pinrt("It is not a dictionary")
```

There are several ways to check a type of value, see: [How to check if type of a variable is string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to return a tuple that keeps track of whether there was an error:

```
def myfunc():
    try:
       return (True, dictionary)
    except BaseException as e:
        return (False, e)

was_successful, return_value = myfunc()

if was_successful:
    do this
else:
    do that
```