# How to check if some datatype is string or list in python?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a check here that if the receiver is just a string. then convert that into list else just pass.

```
  if type(receiver) == str:
        receiver=[receiver]
```

**error:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**

Comment: I recommend doing Maik Hasler's way. It is the most clean and up-to-date method.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama what is that ??

Comment: The upvoted answer that @MaikHasler gave.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if type of a variable is string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string)

Comment: If this code comes up with this error then you have overwritten `type` somewhere earlier in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the type of an instance with the following.

```
if isinstance(receiver, str):
    # do something if it is a string
```

If you just need to check rather it is not a string:

```
if not isinstance(receiver, str):
    # do something if it is not a string
```

Look at [this tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/isinstance) to learn more about the function.

Comment: I just want to check if that is a string or not.

Comment: @dummyfirst Sure, I edited my answer. But your inital question was how to check for a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = '123'
print(str(a))
print(type(a))
```