# How to check string if float or integer?

Tags: python, analyzer, lexical

```
buf=[]
token=[]
def lex():

def read():
    
    f=open('lex.txt','r')
    data=f.readline()
    data=data.split(' ')
    return data

lex=read()

def operator(i):
    
    op=['+','-','/','*','<','>','>=','<=']
    
    if i in op:
        buf.append(i)
        token.append('RELOP')
        return True
def error(i):
    
    digit=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
    
    try:
    
        if i[0] in digit:
            buf.append(i)
            token.append('ERROR')
            return True
    except:
        pass
    
def keyword(i):
    
    keyword=['if','while','for']
    
    if i in keyword:
        buf.append(i)
        x=i.upper()
        token.append(x+'_TOKEN')
        return True
        
def ident(i):
    
    alph=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    
    try:
        
        if i[0] in alph:
            buf.append(i)
            token.append('ID')
            return True
    
    except:
        pass
        
    
def floati(i):
    
    try:
        res = i.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit()
        if res:
            buf.append(i)
            token.append('FLOAT')
            return True
    
    except:
        pass
        
        
        
def integ(i):
    
    try:
        x=int(i)
        buf.append(i)
        token.append('INTEGER')
        return True
    except:
        pass

count=0

for i in lex:
    
    if keyword(i):
        
        print(token[count])
        
        continue
    
    elif operator(i):
        
        print(token[count])
        continue
    elif error(i):
        
        print(token[count])
        continue
    elif floati(i):
        
        print(token[count])
        continue
    elif integ(i):
        
        print(token[count])
        continue
    elif ident(i):
        
        print(token[count])
        continue
    else:
        
        print("Zaaa anan xd")
    
    count+1
    

lex()
```

I am trying to write a lexical analyzer in Python. I want to check an input string from a file for a float or integer, but when I use `float()` my code changes the string type of integer to float and returns as float. I do not want to check string using `float()` or `int()`. I want to append the string to an array without changing it.

Comment: What's in `lex.txt`, and what is the expected output of your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string

Comment: The `lex` function is empty. Is the rest of it supposed to be nested functions? Please fix the indentation.

Comment: Lexical analyizers usually use regular expressions in their parsers to recognize different types of literals.

Comment: @LeonMenkreo - that's a different question - that simply reports whether it is type "string". THIS question is whether the string is a valid representation of a number.

Comment: x 45 5.4 -33 size33 34RR if <= while x this is the inputs

Comment: I have always found this an interesting topic.  Do you intend to require that your tokens be separated by whitespace, so you can use `.split`?  If so, then using regexes on those tokens is easy: `r"\d+"` for integers, `r"\d+(\.\d*)?(E\d+)?"` for floats.  There are several good lexical parser modules for Python.

Comment: You should modify the question to include your sample input.  Presumably, "34RR" is a syntax error.

Comment: *"I do not want to check string using float() or int()"* - why not? You don't have to *use* the result of the conversion - just check whether it throws an error or not. Define a function that does the check - similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/354038/199364 - but add a check for int also.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sir i do not want to use regexes.

Comment: Note that `alph = "abcdefghijkl..."` is a lot easier to type than `alph = ['a','b','c','d',...]` and works exactly the same.

Comment: it converts integer to float when i want to check it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve sir when i want to check integer type of string float or not, it converts integer to float.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you want an integer to be seen as an integer, then you check for integer FIRST - treat it as an integer in that case.

Comment: You must check for integer BEFORE you check for float, otherwise all integers will be seen as floats.  And I don't know what your "error" is doing; you will never get any true integers in this process.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to check if a string is int or float:

```py
def is_int(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Then:

```py
>>> is_int('-73')
True

>>> is_int('2.3')
False
```

But note, the above `is_int()` only checks for `int`. If not, it is not necessarily a `float`:

```py
>>> is_int('foo')
False
```

But you could easily duplicate that pattern for `float`.

Answer (score 0):

The *str* module offers the `isdigit` function, returning `True` if a string represents a digit.

```
str.isdigit("5")
# True
str.isdigit("five")
# False
```

For `float` type, you could write a short function using `try-except`:

```
def check_float(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strs = ["x", "45", "5.4", "-33", "size33", "34RR", "if"]
from re import match
strs = ["18","18.5","s","-35"]
for s in strs:
    if match("^-{0,1}[0-9^]*(\.[0-9]+){0,1}$",s):
        if s[0] == "-":
            s = s[1:]
        if s.isdigit():
            print("int")
        else:
            print("float")
    else:
        print("other")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want, without using regexes.  Notice that this handles negative numbers, which yours did not.  I've removed the called to `error(i)`, since it was pointless.

```
def read():
    return open('lex.txt','r').read().split()

op=['+','-','/','*','==','!=','<','>','>=','<=']
def operator(i):
    if i in op:
        buf.append(i)
        token.append('RELOP')
        return True
    return False

# I don't know what this is doing.  `i` is a string.
def error(i):
    digit=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
    if i[0] in digit:
        buf.append(i)
        token.append('ERROR')
        return True
    return False
    
keywords=['if','while','for']
def keyword(i):
    if i in keywords:
        buf.append(i)
        x=i.upper()
        token.append(x+'_TOKEN')
        return True
    return False
        
alph='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
def ident(i):
    if i[0] in alph:
        buf.append(i)
        token.append('ID')
        return True
    return False
        
def floati(i):
    tmp = i
    if tmp[0] in "+-":
        tmp = tmp[1:]
    if tmp.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
        buf.append(i)
        token.append('FLOAT')
        return True
    return False
        
def integ(i):
    if i.isdigit() or i[0] in "+-" and i[1:].isdigit():
        buf.append(i)
        token.append('INTEGER')
        return True
    return False

def parse(lex):

    for i in lex:
        if keyword(i) or \
            operator(i) or \
            integ(i) or \
            floati(i) or \
            ident(i):
            print(i, token[-1])

        else:
            print(i, "Syntax error")

buf=[]
token=[]
parse(read())
```