# How to check if a variable is a string on not in Python?

Tags: python, string

What function do you use to check what kind of datatype your variable or parameter

Comment: isinstance?....

Comment: `type("") == str`.  However, this may not be necessary/wise/etc.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if type of a variable is string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string)

Comment: @FiddlingBits **no** that is absolutely not how you should be doing that

Answer (score 3):

In Python, the recommended way is to do it with isinstance(), so to see the type of var:

```
isinstance(var, str)
```

Alternatively, you can do it with type():

```
type(var)
```

Using the second way, in a more specific context, if you want to know if var is a string, you can do it this way:

```
type(var) == str
```

Comment: This is not the idiomatic way to do this

Comment: What do you mean? My code is correct, and it works, however, if you think it can be improved please edit it as you see fit.

Comment: I said what I meant, it is not idiomatic. Idiomatically, you would do `isinstance(var, str)`.

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to my attention, i edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the type() function. For example

`type("foo")`

will output
<class 'str'>