# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 3 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am parsing an XSL file using xlrd. Most of the things are working fine. I have a dictionary where keys are strings and values are lists of strings. All the keys and values are Unicode. I can print most of the keys and values using `str()` method. But some values have the Unicode character `\u2013` for which I get the above error.

I suspect that this is happening because this is Unicode embedded in Unicode and the Python interpreter cannot decode it. So how can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 83):

You can print Unicode  objects as well, you don't need to do str() around it.

Assuming you really want a str:

When you do str(u'\u2013') you are trying to convert the Unicode string to a 8-bit string. To do this you need to use an encoding, a mapping between Unicode data to 8-bit data. What str() does is that is uses the system default encoding, which under Python 2 is ASCII. ASCII contains only the 127 first code points of Unicode, that is \u0000 to \u007F1. The result is that you get the above error, the ASCII codec just doesn't know what \u2013 is (it's a long dash, btw).

You therefore need to specify which encoding you want to use. Common ones are ISO-8859-1, most commonly known as Latin-1, which contains the 256 first code points; UTF-8, which can encode all code-points by using variable length encoding, CP1252 that is common on Windows, and various Chinese and Japanese encodings.

You use them like this:

```
u'\u2013'.encode('utf8')
```

The result is a str containing a sequence of bytes that is the uTF8 representation of the character in question:

```
'\xe2\x80\x93'
```

And you can print it:

```
>>> print '\xe2\x80\x93'
–
```

Comment: This was very comprehensive. Thanks. I had a question - Lets say twitter stream, you would not know the encoding upfront. How would you handle that ?

Comment: @karthikr: I find it hard to believe that Twitter doesn't provide the encoding.

Answer (score 29):

You can also try this to get the text.

```
foo.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Comment: After many SO searches, this fixed it for me. My particular usage was in a print due to both Windows and Linux throwing this encoding error.

Comment: This will lose data for any non-ascii, the  correct method is to encode using the correct  encoding.

Comment: This will ignore the non-ASCII character. Your answer is just to ignore the problem?

Comment: If you aren't using non-ASCII characters, then yes.

Answer (score 7):

As here `str(u'\u2013')` is causing error so use `isinstance(foo,basestring)` to check for unicode/string,  if not of type base string convert it into Unicode and then apply encode

```
if isinstance(foo,basestring):
    foo.encode('utf8')
else:
    unicode(foo).encode('utf8')
```

[further read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979004/what-is-the-difference-between-isinstanceaaa-basestring-and-isinstanceaaa/1979107#1979107)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. This work fine for me:

```
str(objdata).encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this issue in a recent project which really is a pain in the rear. I finally found it's because the Python we used in Docker has encoding "ansi_x3.4-1968" instead of "utf-8". So if anyone out there using Docker and got this error, following these steps may thoroughly solve your problem.

1. create a file and name it ***default_locale*** in the same directory of your Dockerfile, put this line in it,

   **environment=LANG="es_ES.utf8", LC_ALL="es_ES.UTF-8", LC_LANG="es_ES.UTF-8"**
2. add these to your Dockerfile,

   **RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales**

   **RUN locale-gen en_CA.UTF-8**

   **COPY ./default_locale /etc/default/locale**

   **RUN chmod 0755 /etc/default/locale**

   **ENV LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8**

   **ENV LANG=en_CA.UTF-8**

   **ENV LANGUAGE=en_CA.UTF-8**

This thoroughly solved my issue when I built and run my Docker again, hopefully this solve your issue also.

Answer (score 0):

for me this works

unicode(data).encode('utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

First find out what character is a unicode in this link https://unicode-table.com/en/2013/

Then in the code use this:

```
{your-string-variable}.replace(u"\u2013", "-")
```

likewise for all the unicodes having error.

Answer (score 0):

While reading an excel file using `openpyxl`, I encountered the same error and I opted to write a function to help me remove any non-ascii characters while keeping the new line character.

```
def clean_string(b_string):
    # Decode bytes object to string and remove non-ASCII characters except newlines
    cleaned_string = ''
    for byte in b_string:
        if byte == ord('\n') or byte < 128:
            cleaned_string += chr(byte)
    return cleaned_string
```

And its usage like:

```
def upload_conditions(request):
    # Condition.objects.all().delete()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        excel_file = request.FILES.get("nfile")
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
        excel_data = list()

        for letter in ["A"]:
            worksheet = wb[letter]
            for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
                row_data = list()
                for cell in row:
                    value = cell.value
                    if value:
                        encoded_string = str(value).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
                        row_data.append(clean_string(encoded_string))
                        
                    else:
                        row_data.append("")
                    
                excel_data.append(row_data)
```

Calling the `clean_string` function on an encoded string, quickly helped clean the `b_string` or a string with `non-ascii` characters.

To encode a string I did it like this:

```
'''
value - a string to encode with ascii like this one - b'Legionnaires\xe2\x80\x99 disease\nwith newline'
'''
encoded_string = str(value).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```