# Beautiful Soup and character encoding

Tags: python, html, encoding, python-2.x

I'm trying to extract text and HTML from a website with Scandinavian characters using Beautiful Soup and  Python 2.6.5.

```
html = open('page.html', 'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

descriptions = soup.findAll(attrs={'class' : 'description' })

for i in descriptions:
    description_html = i.a.__str__()
    description_text = i.a.text.__str__()
    description_html = description_html.replace("/subdir/", "http://www.domain.com/subdir/")
    print description_html
```

However when executed, the program fails with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test01.py", line 40, in <module>
        description_text = i.a.text.__str__()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 19:         ordinal not in range(128)
```

The input page seems to be encoded in ISO-8859-1, if that's any help. I tried setting the correct source encoding with `BeautifulSoup(html, fromEncoding="latin-1")` but it didn't help either.

It's year 2011 and I'm wrestling with trivial character encoding problems, I believe there's a really simple solution to all this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
i.a.__str__('latin-1')
```

or

```
i.a.text.encode('latin-1')
```

should work.

Are you sure it's `latin-1`? It should detect the encoding correctly.

Also, why not just use `str(i.a)` if it happens you don't need to specify an encoding?

Edit: Looks like you need to [install chardet](http://chardet.feedparser.org/) for it to automatically detect encodings.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with Beautiful Soup failing to output a line of text containing German characters.
Unfortunately there are a myriad of answers even on stackoverflow that didn't solve my problem:

```
        title = str(link.contents[0].string)
```

This gave 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)

Many answers do have valuable pointers as to a correct solution.
As Lennart Regebro says at [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 3 2: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387895/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-u2013-in-position-3):

> When you do str(u'\u2013') you are trying to convert the Unicode
>   string to a 8-bit string. To do this you need to use an encoding, a
>   mapping between Unicode data to 8-bit data. What str() does is that is
>   uses the system default encoding, which under Python 2 is ASCII. ASCII
>   contains only the 127 first code points of Unicode, that is \u0000 to
>   \u007F1. The result is that you get the above error, the ASCII codec
>   just doesn't know what \u2013 is (it's a long dash, btw).

For me, it was a simple case of not using str() to convert a Beautiful Soup object to string format. Fiddling with the console's default output made no difference either.

```
            ### title = str(link.contents[0].string)
            ### should be
            title = link.contents[0].encode('utf-8')
```