# Error while importing Wikipedia using pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I'm using Python 2.7 and trying to work with the following code

```
import wikipedia

input = raw_input("Question: ")
print wikipedia.summary(input)
```

I see this error when the code is run:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "wik.py", line 5, in
>   
>       print wikipedia.summary(input)   File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map) UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2013'
>   in position 38: character maps to undefined

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What input are you entering?

Comment: Have you tried `print wikipedia.summary(input).encode('utf8')`?

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 defaults to ASCII, which only maps characters between \u0000 and \u007F1. You need to use a different encoding in order to properly get this character (\u2013 is a long dash) and many others outside of ASCII.

Using UTF-8 should work for you, and I believe this print statement will properly output text:

```
print wikipedia.summary(input).encode("utf8")
```

For more information on this, check this similar question: [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 3 2: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387895/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-u2013-in-position-3).

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks. Will the statement work in Python 3?

Comment: The only thing you need to change is using parentheses with print (syntax difference between Python 2 and 3).