# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014'

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

Running this code creates the `UnicodeEncodeError` below. Encoding is utf-8 but apparently Python ignores it. I'm using python 2.7.14 on Anaconda2.

```
try:
    aux = pd.read_csv('E:\Python_webscraping_Ahmd/news.csv')

except:     
    aux = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(news.columns))
    aux.to_csv('E:\Python_webscraping_Ahmd/news.csv', encoding= 'utf-8', index=False)

with open('E:\Python_webscraping_Ahmd/news.csv', 'a') as f:
    news.to_csv(f, header=False,  index=False)
```

I get error message

```
UnicodeEncodeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-8835f23065f2> in <module>()
     75 
     76 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 77     getDailyNews()
     78 

<ipython-input-12-8835f23065f2> in getDailyNews()
     69 
     70     with open('E:\Python_webscraping_Ahmd/news.csv', 'a') as f:
---> 71         news.to_csv(f, header=False,  index=False)
     72 
     73     cleanData('E:\Python_webscraping_Ahmd/news.csv')

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   1401                                      doublequote=doublequote,
   1402                                      escapechar=escapechar, decimal=decimal)
-> 1403         formatter.save()
   1404 
   1405         if path_or_buf is None:

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in save(self)
   1590                 self.writer = csv.writer(f, **writer_kwargs)
   1591 
-> 1592             self._save()
   1593 
   1594         finally:

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _save(self)
   1691                 break
   1692 
-> 1693             self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
   1694 
   1695     def _save_chunk(self, start_i, end_i):

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _save_chunk(self, start_i, end_i)
   1717                                         quoting=self.quoting)
   1718 
-> 1719         lib.write_csv_rows(self.data, ix, self.nlevels, self.cols, self.writer)
   1720 
   1721 

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.write_csv_rows()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 134: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 3 2: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387895/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-u2013-in-position-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also specify encoding while writing the csv file:

```
news.to_csv(f, header=False,  index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: @m.borhan please accept the answer if it solved your problem.