# How to know the type of a object in a simple way?

Tags: python, object, object-type

I always write code like:

```
str(type(a)).find('int') != -1
```

Or

```
t = str(type(a)).split("'")[1]
```

Is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are asking about [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
>>> a = 1
>>> isinstance(a, int)
True
>>> s = "test"
>>> isinstance(s, str)
True
```

Speaking about the the second example (string type), it is important to note that there is a `basestring` type:

- [What is the difference between isinstance('aaa', basestring) and isinstance('aaa', str)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979004/what-is-the-difference-between-isinstanceaaa-basestring-and-isinstanceaaa)

Answer (score 2):

```
isinstance(a, int)
```

Example:

```
In [4]: a = 5

In [5]: isinstance(a, int)
Out[5]: True
```