# TypeError when checking for instance of str

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function such that if a string or a number is passed, the data s returned in reverse order. Otherwise, it is returned as it is.

Here's my code:

```
def reverse_it(data):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        return data[::-1]
    elif isinstance(data, int):
        return data[::-1]
    else:
        return data
```

This results in an error:

```
  File "play.py", line 10, in <module>
    print reverse_it(9000)
  File "play.py", line 5, in reverse_it
    return data[::-1]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Why can I check for the data type of a `str` object but not for an int?

Comment: `elif isinstance(data, int): return int(str(data)[::-1])`?

Comment: You are successfully checking that `data` is an `int`. The error is from trying to slice the `int` as if it were a string.

Comment: The person who asked the question should define, what a string and a number is. There are several possibilities which differ by Python version.

Comment: I apologize, as I don't know much about python versions. The problem came from trying to slice an int, which is where the error came from. NightShadeQueen's solution ended up working

Comment: NightShadeQueens solution might not be what you expect. Try it with the int 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think should happen here:

```
elif isinstance(data, int):
    return data[::-1]
```

The data type check is successful, but you cannot slice an int.

You could write

```
return str(data)[::-1]
```

Edit: you might also want

```
isinstance(data, basestring)
```

See [What is the difference between isinstance('aaa', basestring) and isinstance('aaa', str)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1979004/562769)

Comment: If data is a number, reverse it. Does the problem come from trying to reverse/slice something that's not a string?

Comment: What you are using is called a slice. It is defined for list-like data structures. Strings are lists of characters (well, not exactly, but you can think of them as lists of characters). I've added a work-around to my answer

Comment: To reverse the digits of a number you must first convert it to a string.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing and it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: @moose I was responding to Thrashmaniac89's comment, which appeared before yours. I assumed you already knew this.

Comment: It said I had to wait 4 more minutes, but I accepted it now. @moose

Comment: @Zac: sorry, my short term memory is not working properly by now. It's too early. And using the phone doesn't help either.