# How to check if a list contains a string

Tags: python, list

I need to iterate through a list and check if the value is a string or an int. Is there any easy way to do this in python?

For example:

`[1,2,3]` would be true.

`["a",2,3]` would be false.

Comment: Why do you need this? It may be better to handle exceptions instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain

Comment: In my opinion, you should have tried to write some code first and posted your failed attempt.  SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 7):

You could do this using [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), which would short circuit once a false condition is met.

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> all(type(d) == int for d in my_list)
True

>>> my_list = ['1', 2, 3]
>>> all(type(d) == int for d in my_list)
False
```

[isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) could be used when calling `all` as well:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> all(isinstance(d, int) for d in my_list)
True

>>> my_list = ['1', 2, 3]
>>> all(isinstance(d, int) for d in my_list)
False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
In [1]: def contains_string(l):
    ...:     return any(isinstance(item, basestring) for item in l)
    ...: 

In [2]: contains_string([1,2,3])
Out[2]: False

In [3]: contains_string(['a',2,3])
Out[3]: True
```

`basestring` handles both "unicode" and "str" string types:

- [What is the difference between isinstance('aaa', basestring) and isinstance('aaa', str)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979004/what-is-the-difference-between-isinstanceaaa-basestring-and-isinstanceaaa)

Note that `any()` would *short-circuit* as well once it knows the result, see more about that here:

- [How do Python's any and all functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant that you need to check through all the values of the list and that only if they were all integers the function would return True, this is how I'd do it:

```
def test(list):
    result=True
    for elem in list:
        if type(elem)!=int:
            result=False
    return result
```